# @IBAction to performSegue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have the following:

```
class Settings: UIViewController {

@IBAction func CitySend(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "senddata", sender: self)
}

@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "senddata" {
        let Mainview = segue.destination as! ViewController
        Mainview.label = textField.text!
    }
   }
}
```

My mainview looks like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var city: UILabel!
var label: String = ""


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    city.text = label
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

im not sure, if this is how i should even do this, but to me the logic is that i only want to allow this segue to pass a string to my label in my mainview if the button is pressed (Like a save button)

However as to what i have made now, nothing happens, and it gives me the 1: signal SIGABRT error, whenever i press the button.

Comment: You have a forced downcast, so probably the destination view controller is. It an instance of `ViewController`

Comment: I have no idea what that means to be honest. But i have the following in my destination view: 

    @IBOutlet var city: UILabel!
    var label: String = ""
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        
        city.text = label
    }

Comment: Where does this string come from? textField.text?

Comment: @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

Comment: Let me just post it in my question to make it more arranged

Comment: If you want it to happen only when the button clicked, then add a global boolian variable , and check if the button has been pressed in the prepareForSegue , if buttonPressed{Mainview.label.text = textField.text!} And also make sure the name of the segue is correct in interface builder (sorry for My english :-)

Comment: What line is the crash reported on?

Comment: Also you did Mainview.label = textField.text!  You need to do: Mainview.label.text = textField.text!

Comment: it crashes when i do the performSegue on my button. The other stuff works perfectly fine. 

its on this line: class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

Comment: @Jeppe C  please check my answer and i will update Github link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code:

### ViewController.swift

```
 import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, SecondViewControllerProtocol{
    @IBOutlet weak var dataLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func navigateToSecondViewControllerOnButtonClick(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        let  secondVC: ViewController2 = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewcont2") as! ViewController2
        secondVC.delegate = self
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)
    }

    func saveData(data: String){
        dataLabel.text = data
    }

}
```

### ViewController2.swift

```
 import UIKit


protocol SecondViewControllerProtocol {
    func saveData(data: String) // this function the first controllers
}

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    var delegate: SecondViewControllerProtocol?

    @IBOutlet weak var dataTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func saveButtonClicked(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        delegate?.saveData(data: dataTextField.text!)
    }
}
```

### Storyboard screenshot:

[image]

Please check my GitHub link below to test sample:

https://github.com/k-sathireddy/PassingDataThroughSegue

Comment: Thank you for your answer :-) But where is the button, referring to "senddata"

Comment: Please check my Github link

Comment: No need to call "performSegue" in button action. I did that is storyboard..please check my sample project and reply..

Comment: i understand what you did, and it works perfectly fine. But i don't want it to change view when i press the button, i only want it to append a string to the label in another view when i press the button. 

- like a save button.

Comment: if we want to pass some data to ViewController2, it must exist. VC1->VC2, in this case it is not possible, because VC2 doesn't exist at that time.

Comment: VC2->VC1 , in this case we can pass data from VC1 to VC2

Comment: I am updating my answer, please check in 5 minutes

Comment: Thank you mate, i will check your answer :-) I hope u understand what i need.

Comment: Thank you very much mate :-) !!

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func CitySend(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "senddata", sender: textField.text)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    switch (segue.identifier, segue.destination, sender) {
    case (.Some("senddata"), let controller as ViewController, let text as String):
        controller.label = text
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i still get the Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error

Comment: Even cleaner:    `case ("senddata"?, let controller...`.

Comment: @JeppeC what line?

Comment: its line 47 in UIApplicationMain